# How to successfully implement my own __contains__ method for an ArrayList class?

Tags: python, class, arraylist, contains

I'm a relatively new python programmer and am trying to fix my **contains** method in my ArrayList class. I want to check if an input value is actually contained in the stored list.

```
def __contains__(self, value):
        """Implements `val in self`. Returns true if value is found in this list."""
        for num in iter(self):
            if(num==value):
                return True
            else: 
                return False
```

Could someone tell me what might be wrong with this code? I test it with a generated list range(100) for the value 50 but it won't return True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tests if `num` is equal to the first value in `self`. You should only `return False` after the whole loop ends and you've shown that `num` wasn't equal to anything in the list since you haven't returned `True` yet.

Also note that the `iter` is implied if you just write `for num in self`. And a normal Python list (`[]`) is essentially a Java `ArrayList` already.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me notice the indentation.